# Far Manager file view customization

Tags: customization, explorer, far

maybe some of you use [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) as a file manager and could help me with this. I want to be able to call a custom command on viewing a file with a specific extension, i.e. when I press F3 (command for viewing the contents of a file), some custom command is executed on that file and the output is shown in Far Manager's view window.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Found what I need - under **Commands > File associations** need to create new entry with needed file mask, then under **View command (used for F3)** add this - **far:view < your command**.

I wanted this to be able to view decompiled Java class files, so I did this:

- file mask: *.class
- view command: far:view < jad -p !.!

Comment: view command should be: view:< jad -p !.!